How to mark a calculated query column as total:sum in Microsoft Access?
How can I ensure for Design View that the "total" line of this calculated column shows "sum"?
It seems to change after running the query and saving it.
What starts as:
TotalRevenue: [Orders]![Quantity]*[Products]![CostPerUnit]

morphs to:
TotalRevenue: Sum([Orders]![Quantity]*[Products]![CostPerUnit])

as shown here:
Showing sum:

showing expression:

from "copilot":
1. Open the Query Design view.
2. Add the Customers, Orders, and Products tables to the query.
3. From the Customers table, add the Country field to the first column in the query grid.
4. Set the Total row (found at the bottom of the query grid) for the Country field to 'Group By'.
5. In the second column of the query grid, create a calculated field named TotalRevenue. To do this:
   - In the Field row, enter: TotalRevenue: [Orders].[Quantity]*[Products].[UnitPrice]
   - This expression multiplies the Quantity field from the Orders table by the UnitPrice field from the Products table.
6. Set the Total row for the TotalRevenue field to 'Sum'.
7. Format the TotalRevenue field as Currency. This is usually done in the properties sheet where you can set the Format property to 'Currency'.
8. Change the caption for the TotalRevenue field to 'Total Revenue' by setting the Caption property in the properties sheet.
9. Save the query as 'Revenue and Cost by Country'.

although I now notice that Copilot actually suggests using the dot notation, so I'm confused on that point.
The generated SQL:
SELECT Customers.Country, Sum([Orders].[Quantity]*[Products].[CostPerUnit]) AS TotalRevenue
FROM Products INNER JOIN (Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID) ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductID
GROUP BY Customers.Country;


i like to go to teh sql view add , Calculate-e as caluclated  the rest makes access on its own
